# speeding up query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with more than 10 million rows and 5 fields (columns). There is an index on `field_1` and I am running the following query:

```
CREATE table t2 
SELECT field_1,sum(field_2) AS field_2, 
       sum(field_3) AS field_3,
       sum(field_4) AS field_4 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY field_1;
```

The data type of field_1 is varchar(200) and for other fields it is double .

This query was not able to produce the result even after running for more than 1 day. Any suggestions on getting the results quickly will be helpful.

Based on suggestions available on web, I have done following changes in my.cnf file present in c:\xampp\mysql\bin:
    key_buffer = 1G
    read_buffer_size = 256M
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 512M
Also I have done this.
    SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size=256*1024*1024

If someone can suggest anything else, it will really make my task easier.

Comment: did you try without the ifnull ? I don't know how much it speeds the process but its unnecessary anyway

Comment: i have to store the result in a table for further processing. I have edited the question also now, kindly take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You are using sum function so I assume values of this columns are numbers.
Change data type to integer or float if they are decimal.

Thanks to that MySQL won't have to cast it to number during execution and opration on numbers are much faster than on strings.

Comment: @Sebas I have changed the datatype to double in source table and now query is being changed to this: create table t2 select field_1,sum(field_2) as field_2,sum(field_3) as field_3,sum(field_4) as field_4 from t1 group by field_1;

Comment: there is nothing more You can do to improve this query. If still it takes over 1 day to execute there may be something wrong with Your database server. I was lately working with 9 millions row table and had some complex queries but they were taking maximum 5 minutes.

Comment: Could you please suggest what can be wrong with the server and where to look for it.One more thing, currently mysqld is not using more than 70,292k of RAM. How can i make it to use more RAM. May be that can help my cause.

Comment: I don't know mysql so well from inside to be able to suggest anything concrete. try to reinstall it with default settings. Did You try to run just select statement without create table, does it takes so long as well?